# How to set subview height constraints for different size classes

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

This is how I have set subview height in regards to superview.I have set constraints for `compact width` and `regular height` class as `View.height = 0.5xheight`. I want to set `View.height = 0.25xheight` for `regular width` and `regular height` class.

[image]

So basically I want to change multiplier to 0.25 for `regular width` and `regular height` class. But I did not find any option to do that. So how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to `Main.Storyboard` and select your size class, here `View as: iPad Pro (wR hR)` and adjust size of your subview and update the constraints.

Comment: Thanks that did it.